# pip install mitmproxy failed " error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None" in windows

Tags: python, pip, mitmproxy

pip install mitmproxy  failed .
command :  pip install mitmproxy==7.0.4
python version : 3.10
VS version : 2019  have add C++ LIBRARY

i check similar ticket but still can't working .  in Visual Studio 2019 folder have CL.exe and also execute command can working.

have try lots of method but still failed .
example :  execute command in VS Command Prompt.

does the latest version not support this mitmproxy module ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FDp3.jpg)

```html
C:\Users\HLI211\PycharmProjects\MobileApp\venv\Scripts>pip install mitmproxy==7.0.4
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Collecting mitmproxy==7.0.4
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/1f/b7/6e0a57ae8916bd9c991b664366ad9b43e69c0f10a8ca085d9aea9b45c520/mitmproxy-7.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<0.13,>=0.11 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from mitmproxy==7.0.4) (0.12.0)
Collecting h2<5,>=4.0
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/2a/e5/db6d438da759efbb488c4f3fbdab7764492ff3c3f953132efa6b9f0e9e53/h2-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting cryptography<3.5,>=3.3
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/b6/32/e82e51a64280b16647af538bbfe4424285a41f01687899405e997a6e39b4/cryptography-3.4.8-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8.1,>=7.0 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from mitmproxy==7.0.4) (8.0.3)
Collecting urwid<2.2,>=2.1.1
  Using cached urwid-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zstandard<0.16,>=0.11
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/b4/79/7b192e51a2952dee3a3c9dbd9208a9838d8d497745a18a5528e2dbfb465e/zstandard-0.15.2.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pydivert<2.2,>=2.0.3
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/ca/8f/86d7931c62013a5a7ebf4e1642a87d4a6050c0f570e714f61b0df1984c62/pydivert-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/ca/8f/86d7931c62013a5a7ebf4e1642a87d4a6050c0f570e714f61b0df1984c62/pydivert-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Collecting asgiref<3.5,>=3.2.10
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/fe/66/577f32b54c50dcd8dec38447258e82ed327ecb86820d67ae7b3dea784f13/asgiref-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting protobuf<3.19,>=3.14
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/ec/2e/309682e1fe979b17d6fec004e8107a953d1300b93c32c397a9c3ca60322e/protobuf-3.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (174 kB)
Collecting blinker<1.5,>=1.4
  Using cached blinker-1.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting kaitaistruct<0.10,>=0.7
  Using cached kaitaistruct-0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing<2.5,>=2.4.2
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/8a/bb/488841f56197b13700afd5658fc279a2025a39e22449b7cf29864669b15d/pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting msgpack<1.1.0,>=1.0.0
  Using cached msgpack-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting tornado<7,>=4.3
  Using cached tornado-6.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: flask<2.1,>=1.1.1 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from mitmproxy==7.0.4) (2.0.2)
Collecting passlib<1.8,>=1.6.5
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/3b/a4/ab6b7589382ca3df236e03faa71deac88cae040af60c071a78d254a62172/passlib-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (525 kB)
Collecting pyperclip<1.9,>=1.6.0
  Using cached pyperclip-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers<2.5,>=2.3 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from mitmproxy==7.0.4) (2.4.0)
Collecting ruamel.yaml<0.17.17,>=0.16
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/d3/cc/248dfb697bb98152c187ced584e505124ed952529d7f8e74b28f6f4d6f31/ruamel.yaml-0.17.16-py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
Collecting publicsuffix2<3,>=2.20190812
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/9d/16/053c2945c5e3aebeefb4ccd5c5e7639e38bc30ad1bdc7ce86c6d01707726/publicsuffix2-2.20191221-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Downloading https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/9d/16/053c2945c5e3aebeefb4ccd5c5e7639e38bc30ad1bdc7ce86c6d01707726/publicsuffix2-2.20191221-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 89 kB 33 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2019.9.11 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from mitmproxy==7.0.4) (2021.10.8)
Collecting ldap3<2.10,>=2.8
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/4e/f6/71d6ec9f18da0b2201287ce9db6afb1a1f637dedb3f0703409558981c723/ldap3-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (432 kB)
Collecting Brotli<1.1,>=1.0
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/6b/11/7d28cd3a5492fed09159e9b37613fdcec7655d93dec664b79d4bb4bb67b8/Brotli-1.0.9-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (383 kB)
Collecting pyOpenSSL<20.1,>=20.0
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/b2/5e/06351ede29fd4899782ad335c2e02f1f862a887c20a3541f17c3fa1a3525/pyOpenSSL-20.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting hyperframe<7,>=6.0
  Downloading https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/d7/de/85a784bcc4a3779d1753a7ec2dee5de90e18c7bcf402e71b51fcf150b129/hyperframe-6.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wsproto<1.1,>=1.0 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from mitmproxy==7.0.4) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from click<8.1,>=7.0->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from cryptography<3.5,>=3.3->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from flask<2.1,>=1.1.1->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from flask<2.1,>=1.1.1->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from flask<2.1,>=1.1.1->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (2.0.1)
Collecting hpack<5,>=4.0
  Downloading https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/d5/34/e8b383f35b77c402d28563d2b8f83159319b509bc5f760b15d60b0abf165/hpack-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.4.6 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from ldap3<2.10,>=2.8->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL<20.1,>=20.0->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography<3.5,>=3.3->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask<2.1,>=1.1.1->mitmproxy==7.0.4) (2.0.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: zstandard
  Building wheel for zstandard (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\HLI211\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplzej_vyj'
       cwd: C:\Users\HLI211\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r18rbh47\zstandard_28fe937167f541f083d847bd1f9ca697
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\zstandard
  copying zstandard\backend_cffi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\zstandard
  copying zstandard\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\zstandard
  copying zstandard\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.10\zstandard
  copying zstandard\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.10\zstandard
  running build_ext
  building 'zstandard.backend_c' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.10
  creating build\temp.win32-3.10\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.10\Release\c-ext
  cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic-ext -Izstd -Ic:\users\hli211\pycharmprojects\mobileapp\venv\include -IC:\Users\HLI211\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\HLI211\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include /Tcc-ext\backend_c.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.10\Release\c-ext\backend_c.obj -DZSTD_SINGLE_FILE -DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY= -DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY= -DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=
  error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for zstandard
Failed to build zstandard
ERROR: Could not build wheels for zstandard, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Your problem is that `pip install zstandard` fails. I suspect you are using Python 3.10 and zstandard does not provide precompiled wheels for 3.10 yet. mitmproxy does not have much to do with this.

Comment: thanks , you are right ,I re-install python 3.9 can install mitmproxy success .